# Coloring of small chessboards on the torus

Tags: recreational-mathematics, coloring, chessboard

Take $\mathbb{Z}[i]\pmod{4-i,1+4i}$.  It has seventeen elements.  Each element $m+ni$ has eight neighbours, that differ from it by $1,-1,i,-i,1+i,1-i,-1+i,-1-i$.
Two copies of this torus can be coloured with the same seventeen colours so that any two colours are neighbours in one of the tori.  The colour at $m+ni$ in the first torus goes to $2m+2ni$ in the second torus.
Three torii of area 25, though different complex periods in this example, can each be coloured in 25 colours so that any two colours are neighbours in one of the torii.  I can't find four torii of area 33?

> ```
>  4     7    10    13    16    19    22  
>  8    11    14    17    20    23     1  
> 12    15    18    21    24     2     5  
> 16    19    22     0     3     6     9  
> 20    23     1     4     7    10    13  
> 24     2     5     8    11    14    17  
>  3     6     9    12    15    18    21
> ```

> ```
> 11     1    16     6    21    11     1  
>  9    24    14     4    19     9    24  
>  7    22    12     2    17     7    22  
>  5    20    10     0    15     5    20  
>  3    18     8    23    13     3    18  
>  1    16     6    21    11     1    16  
> 24    14     4    19     9    24    14
> ```

> ```
> 18     7    21    10    24    13     2  
> 23    12     1    15     4    18     7  
>  3    17     6    20     9    23    12  
>  8    22    11     0    14     3    17  
> 13     2    16     5    19     8    22  
> 18     7    21    10    24    13     2  
> 23    12     1    15     4    18     7
> ```

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: You can replace $1+0i$ and $0+1i$ in Grid 1 with $a+bi$ and $c+di$ in Grid 2 and similar in Grid 3.  Then $m+ni$ goes to $m(a+bi)+n(c+di)$.  I did a long search through $a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h$ which worked, but seems dumb.  If the eight neighbours of the origin, in the three grids, are different, then the 24 neighbours of anything else will also be different.  That doesn't work for four grids, I don't know why not.

Comment: It works also for 5,6,8,9,10,11,12 grids but not 7 or 13.  I think it is to do with the number of elements being a multiple of 3.

Comment: Side note: $\Bbb Z[i]$ (mod $4-i$, $1+4i$) is actually the same as just $\Bbb Z[i]$ (mod $4-i$), since $1+4i = i(4-i) \in \Bbb Z[i]\cdot(4-i)$ already.